# Cannot download file with presigned url to remote server using curl

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, php-curl

I have a question regarding using an AWS S3 presigned URL to download a file to a remote server. I was able to successfully create the presigned URLs for a zip file. If I type the presigned URL into the browser I can successfully download the zip file. However, I also need our users' site to get that zip file, download it to their server and unzip it. So what I did was use PHP CURL and provided the presigned URL for the CURLOPT_URL parameter. However, when I do this the zip file is empty and I get an error message. Since I am using a presigned url it already has the required authorization & signature headers to download the file. My question is why doesn't it work in PHP CURL but only in the browser? What am I not doing right here?

**Example Presigned URL:**
`https://xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-231481972270.s3-accesspoint.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/serenity-pro/serenity-pro.zip?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIATLZLGSYXEHERUI4Z%2F20210913%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210913T042133Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=62ba2cb3d434f8643cd5099b74523234df46b3c9fdb0f5ab75d962c8ab4d0428`

**My Code:**

```
// Download zip file
// The $download_url is the presigned URL I generated for the user
$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen($theme_zip_path, "w+");
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $download_url,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 600,
CURLOPT_FILE => $fp
));
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

**Error Message:**
InvalidRequest The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use Signature Version 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is encountering the same issue the solution is to use CloudFront signed URLs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateURL_PHP.html

```
// Create a CF signed URL
use Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient;

$resourceKey = $cloudfront_url;
$expires = time() + 1800;
$privateKey = 'YOURPRIVATEKEY.pem';
$keyPairId = 'YOURKEYPAIRID';

$cfClient = new Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'YOURREGION',
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);

$download_url = $cfClient->getSignedUrl([
    'url' => $resourceKey,
    'expires' => $expires,
    'private_key' => $privateKey,
    'key_pair_id' => $keyPairId
]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

> curl
> 'https://xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-231481972270.s3-accesspoint.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/serenity-pro/serenity-pro.zip?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIATLZLGSYXEHERUI4Z%2F20210913%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210913T042133Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=62ba2cb3d434f8643cd5099b74523234df46b3c9fdb0f5ab75d962c8ab4d0428'
> --output serenity-pro.zip

1. Insert the URL within quotes
2. add the option --output with file-name as destination

Answer (score 0):

if your url contains https then try adding this

**CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST**

**CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER**

```php
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $download_url,

CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,

CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 600,
CURLOPT_FILE => $fp
));
```

Comment: Thx for the suggestion - I tried it but I am still getting the same result and error message.